# How do I start completely over with the latest version of Ubuntu?

Tags: system-installation

I have an outdated and unsupported version. I have been racking my brain trying to figure out how to download the latest version, I have run into one brick wall after another. Please help a non-tech savy ubuntu fan.

Comment: Visit : http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Answer (score 2):

When doing this, I assume that you have a failing ubuntu partition at the moment right.

1. Get a DVD with at least 1GB space
2. Go to ubuntu's site and download the latest iso, and burn it on a dvd.
3. Put your disc inside your system and reboot.
4. After rebooting, you might already be booting on your dvd, otherwise look for the buttons that let you boot into your bios or which drive to boot from. (Usually they show it for a few secconds when you boot up.
5. Reconfigure your bios to load from a dvd first (These steps differ for each computer, you can look it up on google).
6. After you succesfully booted on your dvd, choose 'Install Ubuntu'
7. When you get to the install part choose remove Ubuntu x.xx
8. **When you continue, you will lose all your personal data!**
9. Continue with the install.
10. After you are finished, take out your dvd and reboot.
11. You successfully installed ubuntu!

Answer (score 0):

There are comprehensive guides to installing Ubuntu here: [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Take care to make backups of anything you wish to keep (documents, pictures, music, etc) before you start.